# Visual basic or me failing on simple code

Tags: vba, excel

Is there anything wrong here?

I get a syntax error message on even the simplest codes i try to write.

Ive tried copying various codes found on the internet but it all fails.

Could there be some basic vb setting that is missing?

I commonly get errors like:

Compile error:
User-defined type not defined
Whenever i try to load simle code pieces from forums.

Am I missing a library?

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
Dim quantity As Integer = 10
End Sub
```

Comment: VBA's kind of like javascript, implicit typing. You can write quantity = 10 and leave the Dim and As Interger out.

Comment: @frenchie: Yes, you can, and that is a Very Bad Idea.

Comment: @vpJohan: See documentation and the many examples there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251750%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub Macro4()
'
' Macro4 Macro
'
Dim quantity As Integer 
quantity = 10
End Sub
```

Do it like this. you can't declare and set a variable on the same line in VBA